# Dropdown CheckList (DDCL) in asp.net MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins

Anyone know how to implement open source DropDown CheckList (DDCL) in asp.net MVC 3?

DDCL, file:///C:/Users/U305158/Documents/Multiselect/dropdown-check-list.1.4/doc/dropdownchecklist.html

I have ListBoxFor control. And trying to implement DDCL for the listbox.

As per documentation, i have referenced all the .js and .css files.

My code:

```
$("#MyListBoxId").dropdownchecklist();
```

When page loads, i am getting javascript error "Object doesn't support the property"

View:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Ids, Model.SelectList, new { style = "Width:100%" })
```

Comment: post your view html as well.

Comment: @MohitArora - View code added